# Why is setuptools installing but still not recognized?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am trying to install a python library using pip and it tells me it needs setuptools so then I try to install setuptools and although everything seems to succeed, it doesn't recognize that it's installed. Any idea what I might be missing here?

```
$ sudo pip install gmusicapi
Downloading/unpacking gmusicapi
  Downloading gmusicapi-7.0.0.tar.gz (147kB): 147kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/.../Library/Logs/pip.log
$ sudo pip install setuptools
Downloading/unpacking setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-18.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462kB): 462kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools
Cleaning up...
$ sudo pip install gmusicapi
Downloading/unpacking gmusicapi
  Downloading gmusicapi-7.0.0.tar.gz (147kB): 147kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/..../Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange. I was able to reproduce your first error, when installing `gmusicapi` without having `setuptools` installed. However, after installation of `setuptools` (`setuptools-18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl`) I was able to successfully install gmusicapi.

You could try:

- install `gmusicapi` in a new virtual environment
- uninstall `setuptools` (`pip uninstall setuptools` - in come cases you might need to uninstall package several times, repeat it untill you see message that the setuptools package is not installed) and install it again

Edit:

I also tried it with `setuptools==18.3.2` and it also worked for me.